# Why am I getting 0?

Tags: java, android, math

I keep getting 0 with the following equation, and I'm sure it is something I am missing, but this has been bugging me for the past few days.

```
int BASE_SIZE = 8;
Point screenSize = new Point(1440,2000);

mMaxSize = mScreenSize.x/BASE_SIZE;

// This line is the line causing issue.
int surfaceViewSize = mMaxSize * ((BASE_SIZE-1)/BASE_SIZE);
```

This is regardless of if I make the variable an integer, if I use Math.round, I make it a double, anything. I can not for the life of me figure this out.

Comment: There's a method that can already get you the screen size, by the way

Comment: `(BASE_SIZE-1)/BASE_SIZE` is zero because Java uses integer division. Maybe you mean `mMaxSize * (BASE_SIZE-1) / BASE_SIZE;`

Comment: yes I use that method to get the screen size, I just didn't feel like inputting that in as this is not in an activity.

And the goal here is to get mMaxScreenSize .x * 7/8. Hence the mMaxScreenSize.x * ((8-1)/8)

Comment: Please change your title according to the [ask].

Comment: whoever tagged this, thank you! I knew it was an issue with integer division but couldn't figure how to resolve it. Casting to a double corrected the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this integer division here:

```
(BASE_SIZE-1)/BASE_SIZE
```

result to be

```
int surfaceViewSize = mMaxSize * 0;
```

you need to cast one of the operands into a double or float

replace your operations with:

```
mMaxSize = 1.0*mScreenSize.x/BASE_SIZE;
int surfaceViewSize = mMaxSize * ((1.0*BASE_SIZE-1)/BASE_SIZE);
```

Comment: *"you need to **cast** one of the operands into a double or float"* and then you proceed without casting *anything*, instead multiplying by the double number 1, and lack of cast making the code not even compile.

Answer (score 2):

```
int surfaceViewSize = (mMaxSize * (BASE_SIZE-1))/BASE_SIZE;
```

Try this its just a braces issue

Comment: No, it's not. It's all about integer division

Comment: To be fair, changing the braces will change the way the integer division is done but in the end xenteros is right: the basic problem is integer division.

Comment: You don't actually need the outer parentheses at all.  But yes, this is the best answer.  There's no point in converting everything to `float` or `double` when you're going to assign the result back to an `int` anyway.  You just have to be smart about the order you do things.